# What is the python equivalent of c++ const-reference copy-constructor arguments

Tags: python, c++, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, const-correctness

One of the great things of C++ is the usage of `const`-reference arguments – using these type of argument, you're pretty much guaranteed objects won’t be accidentally modified, and there won’t be side effects.

Question is, what’d be the Python equivalent to such arguments?

For instance, let’s say you have this C++ method:

```
void Foo::setPosition(const QPoint &position) {
    m_position = position;
}
```

And you want to “translate” it to Python like this:

```
def set_position(self, position):
    self.position = position
```

Doing this will potentially yield a lot of trouble, and many subtle bugs could appear as well. Question is, what’s the “Python equivalent” way of C++ methods which use const references arguments (copy constructor)?

Last time I caught a bug because a I had a bad “C++ -> Python translation”; I fixed this with something like:

```
my_python_instance.set_position(QPoint(pos))
```

… said otherwise, my other choice was to clone the object from the caller… which I’m pretty much sure is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood correctly.

Shortly, there is not one. There are two things you are after which you do not come by in python often. `const`s and copy constructors.

It's a design decision, python is a different language. Arguments are always passed by reference.

#### `const` correctness

It's up to user not to mess up object, and I think it doesn't happen very often. Personally I like const correctness in c++ but I never caught myself missing it in python. It's a dynamic and scripting language so there is no point in looking at the micro optimizations which could be done under argument constness assertion.

#### Copying object

... you don't do it too much in python. In my opinion it's a design decision to offload memory management onto user, because it's hard to come by with a good standard way, e.g. shallow copies vs. deep copies. I guess if you assume, you don't need it that much, there is no point in providing a way for each object (like c++ does), but only for those which do need it.

Therefore, there is no unified pythonic way. There are at least few ways to do it in standard:

1. List `copied = original[:]`.
2. Some objects provide `copy` method, like `dict`.
3. Some objects explicitly provide a constructor (like in c++), `dict` and `list` do so, so you can write `copied = list(original)`.
4. There is a module [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#module-copy), for which you can provide custom methods `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__`. It also has advantage that another standard library work with it - `pickle` for serialization.

The most c++-like way is option 3. - to implement a constructor so it accepts invocation which returns a copy of its argument (when the argument is of the same type). But it might need a bit crafty implementation of ctor, because you cannot do type overloading.

Option 2. is the same, but refactored into a function.

So probably best way is to provide explicit `__copy__`/`copy` methods, and if you're nice support ctor invocation which will call it.

You then as a developer of object can ensure const correctness, and provide a user with an easy explicit way to request a copy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent. The closest is to use the [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) and define the `__copy__()` and/or `__deepcopy__()` methods on your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Write a decorator on the function.  Have it serialize the data on the way in, serialize it on the way out, and confirm the two are equal.  If they are not, generate an error.

Python type checking is mostly runtime checks that arguments satisfy some predicate.  `const` in C++ is a type check on the behaviour of the function: so you have to do a runtime check on the behaviour of the function to be equivalent.

You could also only do such checks when doing unit testing or in a debug build, "prove" it correct, then remove checks on "release" mode.

Alternatively, you could write a static analyzer that checks for const violations using the inspect module, and decorating the immutability of arguments you lack source for, I suppose.  Probably be just as easy to write your own language variant that supports `const` tho.  As in nigh impossible.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of object is `position`? There is very likely a way to copy it, so that `self` has a private copy of the position. For instance, if `position` is a `Point2D`, then either `self.position = Point2D(position)` or `self.position = Point2D( position.x, position.y )` is likely to work.

By the way, your C++ code might not be as safe as you think it is. If `m_position` is a `QPoint&`, then you are still vulnerable to somebody in the outside world modifying the `QPoint` that was passed in, after your function returns. (Passing a parameter as const does not guarantee that the referred-to object is const from the caller's point of view.)